# Show that if $ f $ is a symmetric bilinear form such that $f(u,u)=0 $, $ \forall u \in V$ so $f=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ a vector space of demension $n$ over a field $\mathbb{K}$. Show that if $ f $ is a symmetric bilinear form such that $f(u,u)=0 $, $ \forall u \in V$ so $f=0$.

I could answer this question by using the matrix transformation, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant than mine.

Comment: It's not true if the characteristic of $\mathbb{K}$ is $2$. For other characteristics, use the polarization identity.

Comment: then I think we have to think of characteristic 0.

Comment: I used a matrix with zero diagonal, and took a vector with only two nonzero entries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you consider $f(x,y) = x_1y_2 + x_2y_1$, you have a nonzero symmetric bilinear form ($f((1,0),(0,1)) = 1$) that nevertheless has $f(u,u) = 0$ for all $u$ in characteristic $2$.

For all other characteristics, it's true, since you can then divide $2 f(u,v) = f(u+v,u+v) - f(u,u) - f(v,v)$ by $2$.

Comment: because $2 f(u,v) = f(u+v,u+v) - f(u) - f(v)$?

Comment: Sorry, typo'ed. I meant $f(u+v,u+v) - f(u,u) - f(v,v)$ of course. By bilinearity, you have $f(u+v,u+v) = f(u,u) + f(u,v) + f(v,u) + f(v,v)$. So $f(u+v,u+v) - f(u,u) - f(v,v) = f(u,v) + f(v,u)$. Symmetry now yields $f(u,v) + f(v,u) = 2 f(u,v)$.